# Building keyval arguments using a macro.

Tags: listings, key-value

I try to create the arguments for a package which uses keyval, with macro, but this does not work:

Here is the demo code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=Pascal}
\def\flags{language=Pascal}
\lstset{\flags}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

The first `\lstset` works. The second fails with

```
! Package keyval Error: language=Pascal undefined.
```

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `keyval` approaches all avoid expanding input, so in your `\lstset{\flags}` example the code sees `\flags` and not the content of the macro. The error message here is a bit unhelpful as it is expanded by TeX, so it *looks* like what you expect! You need to expand the input before applying the keyval macro

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=Pascal}
\def\flags{language=Pascal}
\expandafter\lstset\expandafter{\flags}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

(I assume the real problem has this wrapped up inside a macro or similar, where you can
do the appropriate expansion.)

Comment: Brrrr.... I tried one `\expandafter`, did not think of using two. The error message really confused me.

Comment: @Yossi: As I said, the error is misleading (it would be better to put the argument into a toks and then use that for the output, or to use e-TeX's `\unexpanded`).

Comment: @Yossi: Remember that `{` is a token.  So `\expandafter\lstset{\flags}` will stop after expanding `{`.  You need to jump over `\expandafter` *and* `{`; hence, two `\expandafter`s.

Comment: @Matthew: Ah, a nice place to sell `expl3`. Our equivalent is `\keys_set:nV { package } \variable`, and sorts out the expansion for you!